# Setting up TV cards and importing channels in MythTV

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv, tv-tuner

I've been trying to setup any one of my 3 TV cards with Mythbuntu for the past two days and I really could do with some help.... I'm also a complete noob when it comes to Ubuntu/Linux.

What I have:

- Mythbuntu 12.04.3
- Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-4000
- Hauppauge_WinTV-Nova-HD-S2
- TBS 6984 DVB-S2

**Note:** I'm only trying one card at a time then giving up and re-installing.

I installed the firmware using:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

MythTV won't scan for any channels with any of the cards.

However if I run the below I can see all the available channels in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dvb-apps mplayer
scan -x0 /usr/share/dvb/dvb-s/Astra-28.2E | tee channels.conf
```

I then try to import the channels with the channels.conf using the below but that doesn't work either:

```
sudo service mythtv-backend stop
scan /usr/share/dvb/dvb-s/Astra-28.2E > channels.conf
```

When looking at the terminal whilst I'm trying to import the .conf file I get:

```
mythtv FE_GET_INFO ioctl failed (/dev/dvb/adaptor0/frontend0) eno: No such device (19)
```

And when in MythTV Setup and I try to configure a capture card using 'DVB DTV capture card (v3.x)' my Front End reports:

```
Could not get card info for car /dev/dvb/adaptor0/frontend0 subtype: Unknown error
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm just going round in circles and I've exhausted all my Google search terms.

Comment: Are you upgraded to version 0.27 of MythTV? I think Mythbuntu still ships with 0.25. I doubt that'll fix your problem, but you're more likely to find a solution if you're using the latest stable version.